# how to std::move heap allocated char array to std::string

Tags: c++

Is it possible to `std::move` a heap allocated char array(>= 10000 size) to `std::string`. I'm trying to prevent copying `(std::string str(c_arr))` of char array data to `std::string` where `c_arr` is heap allocated.

Comment: What about [repro]?

Comment: look in to https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/ there are no supported constructor what you required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how to std::move heap allocated char array to std::string

By having allocated the char array as part of another std::string. Example:

```
std::size_t char_count = 10000;
std::string str1(char_count, '\0');
char* c_arr = str1.data();

std::string str2 = std::move(str1);
```

If the heap allocated char array wasn't created by a std::string in the first place, then you cannot move it into a std::string. In that case, you must copy the array instead. Or alternatively, if you cannot create the original buffer with std::string, then you could consider not attempting to create a std::string at all.